# How do I set parameter default values that rely on other parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, parameter-passing, default-value

The following code compiles and works as expected.

```
#include <vector>

void function(std::vector<int> vec, int size=1);

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
    function(vec);
}


void function(std::vector<int> vec, int size){
    //code..
    return;
}
```

However, I would like the size parameter's default value to be deduced based on a previous parameter. So for example:

```
void function(std::vector<int> vec, int size=vec.size());
```

But this however results in:
**error: local variable ‘vec’ may not appear in this context**

Which doesn't surprise me; I assume it needs to know the default value at compile time.  So do I make the function templated?  How would I make the function templated in such a way that the parameter is still an int, and the vector, is still a vector of ints, and the size parameter is deduced to be the passed in vector's size by default.

I would not like to have to pass in the size of the vector during the function call.

Comment: `I assume it needs to know the default value at compile time`, that is not true, actually you can using global variable as default argument, but because the **function parameter evaluation order are not defined**, C++ standard explicitly prohibit access parameter when evaluate default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly want a function with a size parameter, and want the size to default to the vector size (instead of just getting it as a local variable), then you could solve this with *two* functions. One taking just the vector, and one taking the vector and the size (without default). Then the one-argument function can just call the second.

So

```
void function(const std::vector<int>& vec, const size_t size)
{
   ...
}

void function(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
   function(vec, vec.size());
}
```

Comment: That's probably the solution I want.  Especially because I'm making std::function objects, and this is the only function that requires a second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need second parameter if it based on the first?

```
    void function(std::vector<int> vec ){
        size_t size = vec.size();
        //code..
        return;
    }
```

Isn't it easier?

Comment: Because he wants the caller to specify a value *different* than the default size.

Comment: Yeah, the function is recursive, with a changing "size value" each time.  I just wanted to avoid passing it in on the root call since it's always going to be vec.size()